# how to copy a lot of images using php

Tags: php, copy

I want to create a php script to copy a lot of images on every page loading.

for example:

image.php

```
<php
// my url array will be a lot of image path from another websites
// like this: $url[] = 'http://domain.com/image/firstnews.jpg';

$url = array();

for($count = 0; $count < count($url); $count++)
{
    if(copy($url[$count], 'temp/' . $newpath))
    {
        // make_thumb() is a function that i have created it
        if(make_thumb($newpath , $thumb))
        {
            unlink('temp/' . $newpath);
        }
    }
}

?>
```

if my images count be 8-10 this is good and work successful but if count of images be grater for example, images count be 12 it can not work and i have some errors:

sometime: 503 Service Unavailable from server

and some time: php time out fo 60 seconds.

I think problem is for `copy()`, but I do't know why?

please help me. i am not professional programmer.

Answer (score 0):

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

Use this line before executing the copy operation.

Comment: Instead of using `0`, use a larger value. Infinite loading is not recommended, and can be a burden for server

Comment: @Raptor, yes you are right and thanks for pointing. But I wrote to use this line only for this script, and it will dynamically also for copying any number of files.